# Convert ODS to CSV using command line when Libreoffice instance is running

Tags: csv, data-conversion, libreoffice, ods

I'm working with an ODS file in LibreOffice, and every now and then I want to convert it to CSV *from the command line*.
I have found two tools for this: `libreoffice --headless --convert-to csv` and `unoconv -f csv` but none of them works when there is an UI instance of LibreOffice running.

Is there a way to convert an ODS file to CSV from the command line, while LibreOffice UI instance is running?

Comment: @tohuwawohu No, I don't receive any error messages because both `libreoffice --headless` and `unoconv` are working as designed. They are not designed to work on the same time as LibreOffice UI is running.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To convert csv on the command line while LibreOffice is running, **just skip the `--headless` parameter**. The following command (run in PowerShell) worked for me  even while `C:\TEMP\Untitled1.ods` resp. `/tmp/Untitled1.ods` was opened in LibreOffice Calc:

### Windows 10 (tested with LibreOffice 7.0.1)

> `& 'C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\soffice.exe' --convert-to csv --outdir C:\TEMP\ .\Untitled1.ods`

Or similar, if the present working directory is `C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\`:

> `.\soffice --convert-to csv --outdir C:\TEMP\ C:\TEMP\Untitled1.ods`

### Linux (tested with LibreOffice 6.4.6)

> `soffice --convert-to csv --outdir /tmp/ /tmp/Untitled1.ods`

On linux, you could alternatively use the `libreoffice` command instead of `soffice` (seems to be linux-specific...):

> `libreoffice --convert-to csv --outdir /tmp/ /tmp/Untitled1.ods`

In all cases, `Untitled.csv` was created in the expected place.

Comment: Ahh, the docs of the --headless parameter is: *"Starts in "headless mode", which allows using the application without user a interface."* (These are the exact words :) )

Comment: And even more interesting: The description of the `--convert-to` flag is: *"(...) It implies --headless."*

Comment: Note the & prefix on Windows if using powershell. This is not necessary if using the "old" Command Prompt.

Comment: This will destroy any utf-8 characters unless you follow the directions here: https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-GB/text/shared/guide/csv_params.html

Comment: @SurpriseDog: Since the question didn't care about encoding parameters, my the answer didn't need to care about, too. BTW: Pointing to an external URL is discouraged since external content may change or disappear. Thus, feel free to embed the relevant information in your own answer.

Comment: @SurpriseDog: BTW, your comment is wrong. I've just tested the command i've proposed with an ods containing a selection of utf-8 characters starting from c486 (Ć, ć, Ĉ, ĉ, Ċ, ċ, Č and so on). The resulting CSV looks perfectly fine.

Comment: This is what I get without adding the special filtes `duod�cimo` This is what I get with it `duodécimo` - I'm glad that it works fine on your file, but I added my comment so that anyone else having this problem has a chance at fixing it. - Cheers!

Comment: @SurpriseDog I've tested again, now with your string, and the resulting csv looks fine both in LO Cals as well as in Notepad++. If you encounter any encoding-specific problems, you should create a new question providing essential information (OS, LO version, i18n settings, application used to open the csv and so on) to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

**Tested with MacOS  :**

```
/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/soffice --convert-to csv myspread.ods
```

This wrote out myspread.csv in the same directory

Answer (score 0):

With more recent versions of LibreOffice, it is possible to generate CSV files on a per-sheet basis for *all* of the sheets in the ods document. This is possible with an additional token -- e.g., see https://git.libreoffice.org/core/+/b8903bc106dad036acb3d117e5c4fc955697fe02%5E%21/ . The sample usage in the commit message:

```
soffice --convert-to csv:"Text - txt - csv (StarCalc)":44,34,UTF8,1,,0,false,true,false,false,false,-1 sample.ods
```